# Javascript accessing a private array

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make it so everytime you click an img of a pack of gum it adds the total price together depending on the gum img that was clicked. It also has to count how many time the imgs were click to show shopping cart item amount. I have to have a private array. But i cant seem to figure out how to call to it so i can get the price of the gum that was clicked

```
var addPrice = function(gum) {

    total = 0;
    if (gum == extra) {
        total += brands.price[0];
    }
    if (gum == twoMint) {
        total += brands.price[1];
    }
    if (gum == trident) {
        total += brands.price[2];
    }
    if (gum == bubble) {
        total += brands.price[3];
    }
    document.getElementById("totalAmount").innerHTML = total;
};

var clear = function() {
};

var createArray = function() {

    var gumArray = function() {

        var brands = [{
            brand: "extra",
            price: 1.50
        }, {
            brand: "twoMint",
            price: 0.25
        }, {
            brand: "trident",
            price: 2.50
        }, {
            brand: "bubble",
            price: 0.10
        }]
    };
};

document.getElementById("extra").addEventListener("click", function() {
    addPrice("extra"); -
    console.log("gum clicked");
});

document.getElementById("twoMint").addEventListener("click", function() {
    addPrice("twoMint");
    console.log("gum clicked");
});

document.getElementById("trident").addEventListener("click", function() {
    addPrice("trident");
    console.log("gum clicked");
});

document.getElementById("bubble").addEventListener("click", function() {
    addPrice("bubble");
    console.log("gum clicked");
};
```

Comment: No such thing as a 'private' object in javascript. Nor is it clear why you'd want it to be.

Comment: @JaredSmith: [Privacy can be achieved in JavaScript via scoping](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html). But I agree with you about the question being unclear. Also, the code is poorly indented, making me uncomfortable.

Comment: Im supposed to use module pattern to make things private, and its poorly indented because it didnt copy paste correctly

Comment: @CameronHanton I just edited your post to correct the indentation.

Comment: What console errors do you see? You'll probably see that `extra` is undefined (ReferenceError). Because you are passing a string, so you need to compare with `"extra"`.

Comment: @JaredSmith Actually, that's the whole problem, the `brands` is private inside two other functions, but the OP wants it exposed.

Comment: @CameronHanton You are not using the module pattern anywhere

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm aware. But exposed to what? 'Private' means different things to different people. In js-land it means restricted in scope, but a lexical closure is not the same thing as an access qualifier in a statically typed classical language. Its clear from the question that the OP doesn't understand that, or what the homework assignment was asking for (leaving aside the whole issue of the fact that this is *obviously* a homework assignment). While this comment may be more explicit, I liked the pithy one I left first better :).

Comment: "*I have to have a private array.*" - What? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to create a module for this code, let me show you an example of a module, it's hard to say just one thing that would turn your code into a module.

You need a function that returns an object that accesses variables from the closure that is created. Those variables are not visible to the outside unless you expose it as part of the module.

```
var cart = (function() {
  // These vars are private, not directly accessible from the outside
  var total = 0;
  // Map for faster access
  var brands = {extra: 1.50, twoMint: 0.25, trident: 2.50, bubble: 0.10};
  // Private function
  function updateUI() {
      document.getElementById("totalAmount").innerHTML = total;
  }

  // The exported module
  return {
      addPrice: function(gum) {
          total += brands[gum];
          updateUI();
      },
      // The outside can get the value of total, but they can't change it directly
      getTotal: function() {
          return total;
      },

      clear: function() {
          total = 0;
          updateUI();
      }

  };
})();

["extra", "twoMint", "trident", "bubble"].forEach(function(id){
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", function() {
   cart.addPrice(id);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The brands array is a local variable inside an inner scope. There is no way to access to the brands array from outside of its closure at least you don't do something like:

```
var createArray = function(){
  return function(){
    return [{brand: "extra", price: 1.50},
      {brand: "twoMint", price: 0.25},
      {brand: "trident", price: 2.50},
      {brand: "bubble", price: 0.10}]
  };
};
```

Then when you need to access to the brands array from addPrice you can do:

```
var brandsArray = createArray()();
```

However it's not a good practice to go in this direction. There are better way to provide what are you looking for. For example to use the module pattern like the Juan Mendes answer.

Comment: Why the extra function call? Maybe you could cache the array so it's not created every time?

Comment: Sure it is. I've provided this answer to give a solution closer to the question but i better edit the answer to not mislead anybody.